# Function of os.environ in python

Tags: python

I am new to python.I am not having any Knowledge of Python, i came across following line of python code

```
os.environ.get('IS_THIS_POSSIBLE', 'FALSE') == 'TRUE'
```

what does os.environ.get Do? Is it accessing something particular to OS internals.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is getting operation system's environment variables. For your code, it's returning the value of os-environment variable 'ENABLE_BONDING_ROUTER', return 'FALSE' if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Most OS's have environment variables -- for example, the `$PATH` variable. Python runs within the OS, and sometimes has need of those environment variables. They can be accessed through the `os.environ` `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

`os.environ` is a bunch of functions to read and write the system environment and `os.environ.get()` returns an environment variable. See [this documnetation page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) for some details.